# Is there any way to get/set the bass and treble of a video or flash object with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, html5-video

Say you link to a video on YouTube (either using embed or the YouTube API) or you just use HTML5 video. In the former case you are dealing with Flash so it seems to be in the realm of possibility. The latter case seems impossible.

Is there anything for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to do it with pure javascript.

You have to look at the webaudio api : https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html

The idea is the following :
The audio stream goes through nodes.

```
[Source node (i.e. your video)]-->[Analyzer node]-->[Your custom js node]
```

And (to play the audio if wanted) :

```
[Source node (i.e. your video)]-->[Output node (i.e. speakers)]
```

The Analyzer node will let you analyze the sound in real time and sampling it by frequencies thanks to a fft (a.k.a. Fast Fourier Transform).

You have now the amplitude of each frequency the fft gives you. So you can grab bass and trebles from it.

You can now plug your custom js node to the analyzer and use the `onaudioprocess` callback to analyze the frequencies given by the analyzer node and do what you want with that.

Here is a quite well documented code I wrote about it : https://github.com/xseignard/webGLWebAudioAPI/blob/master/js/app/audio.js

It's part of the following demo : http://xseignard.github.com/webGLWebAudioAPI/

There is also this article, which provides some good pointers : http://www.smartjava.org/content/exploring-html5-web-audio-visualizing-sound

And the following demo (look at the code) : http://www.smartjava.org/examples/webaudio-filters/

Please note theses demos only work with a recent Chrome

Have fun with it

**UPDATE:** this solution only applies to plain html5 video, not youtube ones as @tim-wintle mentionned.

Answer (score 2):

Xavier's response is very good for the general case, however if you are asking specifically about the YouTube API then no, you cannot do that.

In particular, you should read the YouTube API Terms of Service carefully:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms

In particular, you may not "separate, isolate, or modify the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API".

From a technical perspective, they have taken steps in the flash player to prevent access to the streams, and in the iframe API they have placed the content on a separate domain to prevent this.

Comment: You're right, I only dealed the pure html5 video part of the question. Thanks for the insights Tim.