# Real-time processing of youtube audio

Tags: audio, youtube, youtube-api, web-audio-api

Is it possible to redirect the audio stream using the youtube api to that it can be processed in real-time?

[I know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826330/audio-effects-with-nacl-extension) that if I can somehow get the audio data into ScriptProcessorNode, it can be forwarded to a NaCl module waiting in the background to do the heavy-duty DSP.

Comment: Would that violate the EULA?

Comment: @PhilMurray only if I release something to "users". Not if I just prototype a proof of concept for research purposes.  :)

Comment: That's a fine line you are managing not to fall over ;-) Good luck

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the YouTube HTML5 experience, then you should be able to hook the audio from the  element via createMediaElementSource().  You cannot do this from the Flash-based (or other object-based) experience - so, no go for protected content.

As an aside - Why use a ScriptProcessor to forward to NaCl to do heavy DSP?  Use the Web Audio API itself.

Comment: ..because my code is in C++ and I fear JS :) Could you supply an example? +1

Answer (score 1):

Please see my response here:

[Is there any way to get/set the bass and treble of a video or flash object with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419153/is-there-any-way-to-get-set-the-bass-and-treble-of-a-video-or-flash-object-with/13460016#13460016)

Also, although in theory it may be possible via a C++ application, I would also suggest that you read the YouTube terms of service carefully - in particular you can't separate the audio or video streams, or mofify them.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms